# d3heatmap - dendrogram row names and colnames without dendrogram plot

Tags: r, d3heatmap

Is there any possibility to delete dendrogram plot and remain ordering of rownames and colnames like it works with `dendrogram = 'both'`?

E.g.

```
d3heatmap(mtcars, colors = 'Blues')


d3heatmap(mtcars, dendrogram = 'none', colors = 'Blues')
```

Both outputs look different but I want to get the same plot as in the first example without dendrogram. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a <- d3heatmap(mtcars,  dendrogram = 'both', colors = 'Blues')
b <- d3heatmap(mtcars,  dendrogram = 'none', colors = 'Blues')
b$x$matrix <- a$x$matrix
b$x$image  <- a$x$image
b
```